# Minor edits—tags modified—, while the text is left untouched

Tags: discussion, editing

This thing bothers me a little: I see a lot of (new) questions that are edited just for adding or removing tags, while the text body is left untouched, even if it needs (sometimes obvious) editing.

I think this should be addressed somehow, but I’m not exactly sure what would be the best way.

Comment: I'm amused that this post comes from someone who's recent edit comment was "deleted 1 characters in body". There is a crazy trend of super minor edits here, particularly the people who do edits only to capitilise Google or Facebook.

Comment: @JohnC That particular answer didn’t needed more edits. Besides, the point is: edit everything that needs to be edited, not just one part of the question.

Comment: Why does it bother you?  They have done some useful work, even if they havent done all possible useful work!

Comment: Remember that when you have enough reputation points, you can edit tags using the "edit tags" tool. Often, when I see a question is obviously incorrectly tagged, but I don't have time to edit the text (if it needs it) I'll just edit the tags and either someone else will edit the text or I'll get back to it later.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Unless the change is done through the suggested edits mechanism where you can reject the edit as "too minor" there's not a lot you can do if someone has more than 500 reputation.

At [that point](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/privileges/retag-questions) they can retag questions at will.